# How to echo data into 3 columns in a table in php?

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop, html-table

My code only worked for 6 datas for 2 rows since I ordered it by asc and desc limit 3,
but I want to echo all the data from database in exactly 3 columns and n rows.
Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped mt30">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $sql = "select * from services order by id desc limit 3"; 
            $result = mysql_query ($sql);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['servies']?></td>            
            <?php }?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
        $sql = "select * from services order by id asc limit 3"; 
        $result = mysql_query ($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <td> <?php echo $row['servies']?></td> 
        <?php }?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The query should be finished before the html

Comment: yes but  i am trying to get in 3 columns and rows can be long...

Comment: You are using deprecated methods. Do you read the php doc before you use functions or just copy paste from some horrible tutorial?

Comment: Please note that the use of `mysql_query` and other `mysql` functions in PHP is extremely outdated. You should relearn this with the `mysqli` extension and it's related functions.
Also, the associative array key 'services' is spelled incorrectly, unless you meant to type 'servies'.

Comment: with out database only in html it is this code:


            <table class="table table-striped mt30">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td> Double Bed</td>
                  <td> Free Internet</td>
                  <td> Free Newspaper</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>60 square meter</td>
                  <td> Beach view</td>
                  <td> 2 persons</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td> Double Bed</td>
<td> Free Internet</td>
<td>Breakfast included</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `limit`. User `order asc` or `desc`. In while loop keep a flag for print `<tr>` and `</tr>`. Just like this...

```
<?php
    $sql = "select * from services order by id asc";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
?>
<table class="table table-striped mt30">
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $i = 0; $trEnd = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($i == 0){
                echo '<tr>';
            }
            echo '<td>'.$row['servies'].'</td>';
            if($i == 2){
                $i = 0; $trEnd = 1;
            }else{
                $trEnd = 0; $i++;
            }
            if($trEnd == 1) {
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        if($trEnd == 0) echo '</tr>';
     ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo...... soooo... much I was trying since this morning!!

your awesome!! it worked!!

Comment: Many Thanks Happy Days!

Answer (score 0):

You should put `<tr>` tag after print every three records,

```
<table class="table table-striped mt30">
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      $result = mysql_query ("select * from services order by id desc");
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      { 
        if($i % 3 == 0) {
         echo "<tr>";
        } ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['servies']?></td> 
        if($i % 3 == 0) {
         echo "</tr>"
        }
        $i++;
      } ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: with out database only in html it is this code: it works exactily i want!! but i am trying to get it in php

 <table class="table table-striped mt30"> <tbody> <tr> <td> Double Bed</td> <td> Free Internet</td> <td> Free Newspaper</td> </tr> <tr> <td>60 square meter</td> <td> Beach view</td> <td> 2 persons</td> </tr> <tr><td> Double Bed</td> <td> Free Internet</td> <td>Breakfast included</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `limit 3`, because you want n row, and `limit 3` will get you 3 rows.
If you want to display only 3 columns from DB, select those 3 columns like: `SELECT col-1, col2, col3`, or select all and display what you want using PHP.

Comment: with out database only in html it is this code: <table class="table table-striped mt30"> <tbody> <tr> <td> Double Bed</td> <td> Free Internet</td> <td> Free Newspaper</td> </tr> <tr> <td>60 square meter</td> <td> Beach view</td> <td> 2 persons</td> </tr> <tr><td> Double Bed</td> <td> Free Internet</td> <td>Breakfast included</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>